# Smallest positive integer k such that the given condition is satisfied

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find smallest $k$ such that $2a+k$ divides $a^2 + ak$  where $a$ is a variable among natural number greater than $50000$ (i.e. from varying a we need to get a unique number for whose k value is the most minimum )  My process i subtracted $a((2a+k))$ to get the condition that $2a+ k$ divides $a^2$ i dont know what to do next

Comment: What might help is that we must have $2a+k\mid a^2$

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Note that $a\times (2a+k)=2a^2+ak$ so, subtracting off $a^2+ak$ we also get that $2a+k$ divides $a^2$.

Comment: @lulu See also my hint, that means that the solution is easy once we have the prime factors of $a$.

Comment: @Peter Right, exactly.

Comment: Sorry i mean that only , how does that correlate to prime factorization?

Comment: @lulu if we have number lets say 50001 then what will be the least k ?

Comment: Follow the hint you were given.   We know the (positive) divisors of $5001^2$ are $\{1,  3 , 9 ,1667 ,5001 ,15003 ,2778889 , 8336667 ,25010001\}$.  Since $2a=10002$ the least one we can reach with a positive $k$ is $15003$ so...

Comment: Sir my question was a bit different i was asking for smallesk k such that there exist a greater than 50000 and  some natural number b such that 1/a+1/(a+k) = 1/b js fulfilled , we need to find the minimum out of all possible varying a and b

Comment: And yes Sir i got the hint of yours @lulu but didnt get how to find overall minimum

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  The way it reads now, I had assumed that $a$ was fixed and that you sought the least positive $k$ with the desired property.  Indeed,  in the comments you specified a value of $a$.  If you meant something else, edit your post to clarify that.

Comment: @lulu Sir the problem is like a is variable and we need to find such k for which minimim of 2a+k is also that it divides a^2

Comment: Sure Sir editing it

Comment: Edited Sir :) ..

Comment: Well, I expect you are going to have to do a search.  Random trials give an example with $k=150$ (specifically, $a=5550$).  So, you just need to search below that.

Comment: Please include the source of this problem in your post.  Increasingly, it looks more like a programming challenge than a math problem.  Perhaps there is a way to address it algebraically, but I expect it is much faster to just do the simple search.

Comment: Please provide a link to the relevant olympiad.  I am somewhat skeptical that this can be done without some computer work, but anything is possible.

Comment: Note:  If you are disagreeing with the solution posted by @S.Dolan, please explain in detail why it is wrong.  That user claims that $(a,k)=(50721,319)$ is a solution and, indeed, $2a+k=101761$ divides $a^2=2572619841$ and indeed the quotient is $25281$.  So, why exactly isn't that a solution with $k<1001$?

Comment: I didnt downvoted it Sir , the answer key maybe incorrect but yeah sure i think  Sir method is correct

Comment: @lulu  I can assure you that I didn't use a computer. (I did use a pocket calculator for $A(2A+1)\ge 50000$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $k$ have  gcd $G$, with $a=AG,k=KG$. Then $A$ and $K$ are coprime and $2A+K$ is a factor of $A(A+K)G$. Therefore $2A+K$  is a factor of $G$ and we can let $G=(2A+K)H$.

We shall now show that solutions with $H>1$ and/or $K>1$ necessarily lead to relatively large values for $k$ and we can then find the smallest solution with $H=K=1$.

If $H\ge2$, then $G>4A$ and so $G>2\sqrt a$ and so $k\ge 448$.

If $H=1$ and $K\ge2$, then $G>2A$ and so $G>\sqrt {2a}$ and so $k\ge 633$.

If $H=K=1$ then $a=A(2A+1)$ and $k=2A+1$. The smallest solution of $A(2A+1)\ge 50000$ has $A=159$ and then $a=50721,k=319$.

Comment: Wonderful answer Sir thanks

Comment: I'm glad to be of help.  I do however wish people would not downvote answers (and questions) without explaining why.

Comment: Yes Sir definitely, i didnt downvoted this though :)

Comment: That's fine! I've added a bit more explanation in case that's of use.